# What does hash (#) sign do outside loops in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I've just come across the use of the hash sign outside of a loop in sass and I'm not sure what it's used for or what the reason for it is.

What's the difference between these two examples please? They both output the same css but the first doesn't allow classes only elements. Why is the first example in use in some places?

```
#{h1, h2, h3, h4, h5}
{
  color: #000;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5
{
  color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [looking at the documentation first?](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_).  (see also:  http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#sass-script-strings)

Comment: I've been looking through their docs all morning and not found that! Thanks for pointing me to it.

Comment: Searching the page for `#{` would have found it.

Comment: It still doesn't answer my question though. In my question above why do some write as the first example. From the docs it looks like it's only used with variables.

Comment: To be fair I had no idea what it was used for when I asked the question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`#{}` is used for string interpolation: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_

> There is one exception to this, though: when using #{} interpolation, quoted strings are unquoted. This makes it easier to use e.g. selector names in mixins. For example.

So this technique is used sometimes to allow using sass values in selectors. E.g.:

```
$gutter: 10;

.grid#{$gutter} {
    background: red;
}
```

Now to your question. I really don't see any reason why would anybody use string interpolation in this selector:

```
#{h1, h2, h3, h4, h5}
{
    color: #000;
}
```

My best guess is that sass variable will be added later to that selector, or the selector will be completely replaced with a variable.

Comment: Thanks @jzelenkov very helpful! And sorry for not spotting this in the docs first like cimmanon pointed out!

Comment: This is actually an interesting question. Where did you see that sass code? Or is it proprietary software?

Comment: I saw this in the Typomatic library, not exactly the same but from looking at the docs I can't see the need for using interpolation https://github.com/andrejmlinarevic/typomatic/blob/master/assets/sass/_typomatic.scss#L48