# What does # mean in SCSS

Tags: scss-mixins

what does # mean in SCSS. I just want to understand what it means.

```
    @mixin hoverFocus($property, $value) {
      &:hover, &:focus {
      #{$property}: $value;
      } 
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does hash (#) sign do outside loops in SASS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885582/what-does-hash-sign-do-outside-loops-in-sass)

Comment: Thanks for that :)